# How to sleep and wake() in Future::poll()?

Tags: rust, future

I want to add sleep to avoid busy loop in Future::poll(), expect the finally effect is that runtime call poll() every second, the fifth second will return Poll::Ready(()).

According to my understanding, poll() is be called in first, this.sleeper.poll(cx) will return Poll::Pending immediately, cx.waker().wake_by_ref() will make current task to execute again immediately.

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use pin_project_lite::pin_project;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
pin_project! {
    struct Delay {
        when: Instant,
        #[pin]
        sleeper: tokio::time::Sleep,
    }
}

impl Delay {
    pub fn new(when: Instant) -> Self {
        Self {
            when,
            sleeper: tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1))
        }
    }
}

impl Future for Delay {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        if self.when < Instant::now() {
            Poll::Ready(())
        } else {
            let this = self.project();

            // I want to add sleep to avoid busy loop.
            this.sleeper.poll(cx);

            // here will make CPU busy loop, uninterrupted call poll()
            cx.waker().wake_by_ref();

            // expect five "1", but will get many "1"
            print!("1");

            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let when = Instant::now() + Duration::from_secs(5);
    let delay1 = Delay::new(when);
    delay1.await;
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=030fbade7a2f1e5df50c4774fc06fdf1

Comment: Looks like you want [`interval()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.interval.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here. First and simplest, when your future is delegating to another future in `poll()`, you do not need to call the waker at all — the other future will do that. In this case, the `Sleeper` takes care of getting the waker called at the right time, causing *your* future to be polled again.

Second, you're ignoring the return value of the `sleeper.poll()`. If it returns `Poll::Ready`, you need to make sure you don't poll it again — either do something else, or replace `self.sleeper` with a new `sleep()`. Polling a future again after it returned `Poll::Ready` is not meaningful, and has consequences left up to the future (often a panic).

Comment: 1. this code from: https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/async,  don't consider the practicality, just for better understanding. I found cx. wake().wake_ by_ fef() will cause busy loop, so I add the sleep.

Comment: 2. In fact, I have tried it locally according to sleeper.poll() results to return data, but the results are similar to the current results. If you think it can solve the problem, please provide the code. Thank you!

Comment: this is attempt that match sleeper.poll(), it still have the problem, it is sleep 1 second, not sleep five seconds. url: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35695274fedcf72477b791b8c99fd659

Comment: Third, you can't expect the `Sleep` to wake only once - it can wake many times.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I resoved this problem by changing Sleep to Interval and call poll_tick().

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use pin_project_lite::pin_project;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::time::Sleep;
pin_project! {
    struct Delay {
        when: Instant,
        #[pin]
        sleeper: tokio::time::Interval,
    }
}

impl Delay {
    pub fn new(when: Instant) -> Self {
        Self {
            when,
            sleeper: tokio::time::interval(Duration::from_secs(1))
        }
    }
}

impl Future for Delay {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        println!("0");
        if self.when < Instant::now() {
            println!("1");
            Poll::Ready(())
        } else {
            println!("2");
            let this = unsafe {self.get_unchecked_mut()};
            //let this = self.project();
            this.sleeper.poll_tick(cx);
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let when = Instant::now() + Duration::from_secs(5);
    let delay1 = Delay::new(when);
    delay1.await;
}
```